# Is it possible to extend Firebird table name length?

Tags: firebird, firebird-embedded

I'm a Firebird newbie here. I'm trying to use Firebird Embedded from an ASP.Net application. Everything connects fine but I'm running into problems with the length of column names. I'm trying to create a table named "Orchard_Framework_DataMigrationRecord." I keep getting an exception which says "Name longer than database column size." After some investigation, I've seen that a number of people have mentioned that Firebird has a column name length limit of 30 characters.

Is that correct and if so is there any way to change it? In my case, I can't change the name of the table; it really has to be that long.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to change the maximum identifier length, it's an implementation limit. There is a plan to remove this limitation but in current version (2.5) the max identifier length is 31 characters.

Comment: And this limit will stay at least for upcoming FB 3.0.

Comment: This is a shame; there's literally no way I can use FB for this project sadly.

Comment: Firebird 4 will extend this to 63 characters

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be fixed as of Firebird version 4.0 Alpha 1: [Increase maximum length of object names to 63 characters](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-749)